# UnicodeDecodeError when editing HTML code with Python

Tags: python, encoding, python-unicode, mitmproxy

I'm using `mitmproxy` to manipulate the returning HTML code of webpages.
When I'm using commands on that HTML code I got `UnicodeDecodeError`.

I tried to do anything, and read any post here and still nothing worked for me.

Two examples of many things I already tried:

```
msg.response.content = unicode(msg.response.content, errors='ignore'))
msg.response.content = msg.response.content.decode('utf8').encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

How can I deal with that?

Comment: Are the pages in question actually UTF-8?

Comment: Pretty sure that they are UTF-8.. How can I validate that?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] including the line of code which throws the `UnicodeDecodeError`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mitmproxy.flow.decoded` context manager, like so:

```
from mitmproxy.flow import decoded

def response(context, flow):
    with decoded(flow.response):
        flow.response.content = flow.response.content.replace("Google", "Noogle")
```

From the source:

> A context manager that decodes a request, response or error, and then
>           re-encodes it with the same encoding after execution of the block.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>    with decoded(request):
>         request.content = request.content.replace("foo", "bar")
> ```

Note: I used mitmproxy on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm using lower version of libmproxy, but still using `libmproxy.http.decode`

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you are decoding correctly, you'll need to look in the source code of the HTML page for something like `<meta charset="utf-8">` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">`. The charset value is the encoding that the page is saying it is using.

if running `type(msg.response.content)` returns that the type is str, then you need to run `msg.response.content = msg.resposne.content.decode(u'utf-8')` where "utf-8" is the encoding the page says it is using. This could also be something like ISO-8859-1 or windows-1251 or ASCII.